# which the best way for integrating linkedin to ROR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I want to give access to my application using Linkedin like http://www.hitch.me/ in ROR application. I am new to ROR please suggest me the best solution also if any one of have done this already please provide me with sample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look at OmniAuth for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Misha said try [Omniauth](http://github.com/intridea/omniauth)

more detailed **example** you can see from this post.

http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16

**provider images:**

https://github.com/intridea/authbuttons